# Symfony left join query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

I've got the following query which is running correctly:

```
$q = $this->createQuery('e')
     ->where('e.Persons_idUser =?', $request)
     ->leftJoin('e.JobTitles jt')
     ->leftJoin('e.EmploymentLevels el');
```

but when I'm iterate through the result and try to access the fields from the left join:

```
 foreach ($work as $w){
   echo $w->employername;
   echo $w->jobtitle; // this is from the left join
   echo $w->employmentlevel; // this is from the left join
 }
```

I got the following error message:
     Unknown record property / related component "jobtitle" on "Experiences"

Anyone got a clue? How do I echo a field from a left join?

Comment: You'll need to do something like `$w->EmploymentLevels->employmentlevel`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    foreach ($work as $w){
        echo $w->employername;
        foreach($w->JobTitles as $job){
            echo $job->jobtitle; // this is from the left join
        }
        foreach($w->EmploymentLevels as $employ){
            echo $employ->employmentlevel; // this is from the left join
        }
    }

?>
```

This will work as symfony returns array of objects and the elements from join table come under child array

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
foreach ($work as $w){
 echo $w->employername;
 echo $w->JobTitles->jobtitle; // this is from the left join
 echo $w->EmploymentLevels->employmentlevel; // this is from the left join
}
```